# start_lvl Ignored in Custom walker_nav_menu

Tags: php, functions, menus, html, walker

This is my first project involving WordPress and I've got stuck trying to create a custom walker for a footer menu.

I basically want to change the menu from the `<ul> <li></li> </ul>` structure to a `<p> <span></span> </p>` structure.

The menu and stuff is displaying file and I have been able to adjust the `start_el` and `end_el` functions without issue so I now get this:

`<ul> <span>*link*</span> <span>*link*</span> </ul>`

Which is obviously half way there, I have written the `start_lvl()` and `end_lvl()` tags as shown below but they are ignored by WordPress - nothing I put in them (even `die()`) is executed (which is a bit suspicious) but I know the class is being called because of the `start_el()` function.

```
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output = "\n<p class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
}

function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $output .= "\n</p>\n";
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening - have I missed something really obvious!?

I am running the latest version of WordPress on Apache with PHP `5.3.6` if it helps.

Thanks in advance,

Felix :)

Comment: Based on what you've shown all the obvious stuff looks correct.

Comment: Cross reference http://wordpress.org/support/topic/start_lvl-ignored-in-custom-walker_nav_menu

Answer (score 8):

Your my_extended_walker class is OK, but when you call the **wp_nav_menu** function use the **items_wrap** parameter.

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap' => '<p>%3$s</p>', 'walker'=>new my_extended_walker() ) );
```

The start_lvl is used for children elements.

Comment: *The start_lvl is used for children elements.* you just saved a lot of things in my life

Answer (score 3):

Ok, not sure what I read wrong when I posted this, but your whole class should be something like this:

```
class my_extended_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $output .= "\n<p class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $output .= "\n</p>\n";
    }
}
```

And then pass the 'walker' as a parameter when you call [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

`wp_nav_menu( array( 'walker'=>new my_extended_walker() ) );`

If you've got that you should be fine. I am looking at working code that does just that. I don't know about putting `<p>` tags in there though. You may get invalid markup.

Comment: Hi, yeah i've done that below is the full class,

Comment: class BB_Nav_Footer_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

 function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
  $output = "\n<p class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
 }
 
 function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
  $output .= "\n</p>\n";
 }
}

Comment: I've tried using `<div>` instead of `<p>` just to see if I can get those functions to do anything but so far no joy :(

Comment: The `<div>` and `<p>` shouldn't break the Walker but might result in invalid markup. You have `$output =` and not `$output .=` in your `start_lvl`. That could be causing trouble. Is that the complete Walker you posted?

Comment: Hi yeah I fixed the `.=` bit this is now the complete class (I removed the `start_lvl()` and `end_lvl()` functions to see if they made a difference) - http://pastebin.com/zfcBxHd8

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about fetching all of the navigation menu items using the built-in function: [`wp_get_nav_menu_items();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) and manually outputting the contents?

**[Example :: Building simple menu list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items#Building_simple_menu_list)**

```
    // Get the nav menu based on $menu_name (same as 'theme_location' or 'menu' arg to wp_nav_menu)
    // This code based on wp_nav_menu's code to get Menu ID from menu slug

    $menu_name = 'custom_menu_slug';

    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

    $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '">';

    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
        $title = $menu_item->title;
        $url = $menu_item->url;
        $menu_list .= '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
    }
    $menu_list .= '</ul>';
    } else {
    $menu_list = '<ul><li>Menu "' . $menu_name . '" not defined.</li></ul>';
    }
    // $menu_list now ready to output
```