# JSON file export of nav menu

Tags: menus

I am trying to export the essence of my wordpress site's menu in json notation.

I want to extract some details like id, type, name, sub-item and want to construct a Json object like below.

Item -

```
{
  id: 'wp entity id',
  name: 'name of the category|taxonomy|post|page',
  type: 'post|category|page',
  children: [array of Items]
}
```

where,

- 'children': here represents sub-items
- 'type': this represents type of item, ie., either a post link, page link, category link, custom link.
- 'id': if item is a category link, id will be category id.
- 'name': name of the category, post, page.

I have spent hours, but couldn't figure out a way to achieve this, kindly shed some light. Thanks.

Edit:
Example of what I am trying to achieve,
Suppose I have a menu like below,

```
-0-------1--------2-------3+- level/depth
 |
 |\___ Lobby
 |
 |\___ Projects
 |       |\___ Project A
 |       |       |\___ Review
 |       |       |\___ Comments
 |       |       \____ Download
 |       \____ Project B
 |               |\___ Review
 |               |\___ Comments
 |               \____ Download
 |\___ Blog
 |
 \____ About
         |\___ Legal
         \____ Contact
```

I want to represent this menu as an object.

```
{
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'lobby',
      type: 'page',
      children: []
    },
    {
      id: '12',
      name: 'Projects',
      type: 'category',
      children: [{
                   id: '12',
                   name: 'Project A',
                   type: 'category',
                   children: [ ... ]
                }]
    },
  ...
  ...
    {
      id: '15',
      name: 'blog',
      type: 'page',
      children: []
    },

  ...

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I still do not understand what you're trying to achieve in the context of WordPress. Are you trying to create a menu that generates children? Does Menus in the Admin panel not suffice or a [WP_Nav_Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function)?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I am trying to export the essence of my wordpress site's menu in json notation.

Comment: Ok, that's a pretty important portion of this question. You may want to add this toward the top so responders know what to aim for.

Comment: How can I go though each of the wordpress menu item and take what I want and construct my object?

Comment: I don't have the time to cook up the code but I'd consider using a custom walker to spit out your code-- something like this one: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72777/21376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, modified it to suit my needs,

Menu Item class:

```
class Menu_Item{
    private $object;
    private $object_id;
    private $link_name;
    private $link_value;

    public function __construct($object, $object_id, $linkname, $linkvalue){
      $this->object_id = $object_id;
      $this->object = $object;
      $this->link_name = $linkname;
      $this->link_value = $linkvalue;
    }

    public function get_link_name(){
      return $this->link_name;
    }

    public function get_object_id(){
      return $this->object_id;
    }

    public function get_link_value(){
      return $this->link_value;
    }

    public function get_object(){
      return $this->object;
    }
}
```

JSON generator:

```
$menu_name = 'main-menu'; //menu name slug
$menu_json_data_string = '{';

if ($menu_name) {
  $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu_name );

  $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

  //initialize two menu item arrays
  $main_menu_item_array = array();
  $sub_menu_item_array = array();//defined as 2d array
  //define two menu item arrays first
  for($i=0;$i<count($menu_items);$i+=1){
    $current_menu_item_obj = $menu_items[$i];

    if($current_menu_item_obj->menu_item_parent == "0"){ //main menu item found
      //define a new menu_item object
      $menu_item_obj = new Menu_Item($current_menu_item_obj->object, $current_menu_item_obj->object_id, $current_menu_item_obj->title, $current_menu_item_obj->url);
      $main_menu_item_array[$current_menu_item_obj->ID] = $menu_item_obj;
    }else{ //sub menu found
      $menu_item_obj = new Menu_Item($current_menu_item_obj->object, $current_menu_item_obj->object_id, $current_menu_item_obj->title, $current_menu_item_obj->url);
      $sub_menu_item_array[$current_menu_item_obj->menu_item_parent][] = $menu_item_obj;
    }
  }

  $menu_item_json_array = array();
  foreach($main_menu_item_array as $each_main_menu_key=>$each_main_menu_item){
    $each_menu_item_link_name = $each_main_menu_item->get_link_name();
    $each_menu_item_link_value = $each_main_menu_item->get_link_value();
    $each_menu_item_object_id = $each_main_menu_item->get_object_id();
    $each_menu_item_slug = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "_", $each_menu_item_link_name));
    $obj = $each_main_menu_item->get_object();
    $type = ($obj=='meta_category')?'meta':'main';
    $each_menu_item_string = '"'.$each_menu_item_slug.'":{"id": "'.$each_menu_item_object_id.'", "type": "'.$type.'", "url":"'.$each_menu_item_link_value.'","name":"'.$each_menu_item_link_name.'"';

    if(array_key_exists($each_main_menu_key, $sub_menu_item_array)){ //has sub menu item
      //count submenu items
      $count_sub_menu_item = count($sub_menu_item_array[$each_main_menu_key]);
      //put each sub menu item into an array
      $submenu_item_list_main_string = ',"children": [';
      $submenu_item_list_array = array();
      foreach($sub_menu_item_array[$each_main_menu_key] as $each_sub_menu_item){
        $obj = $each_sub_menu_item->get_object();
        $type = ($obj=='meta_category')?'meta':'main';
        $each_sub_menu_item_string = '{"id": "'.$each_sub_menu_item->get_object_id().'", "type": "'.$type.'", "url":"'.$each_sub_menu_item->get_link_value().'", "name":"'.$each_sub_menu_item->get_link_name().'"}';
        $submenu_item_list_array[] = $each_sub_menu_item_string;
      }
      $submenu_item_list_string = implode(",", $submenu_item_list_array);
      $submenu_item_list_main_string .= $submenu_item_list_string;
      $submenu_item_list_main_string .= ']';
      $each_menu_item_string .= $submenu_item_list_main_string;
    }
    $each_menu_item_string .= '}';
    $menu_item_json_array[] = $each_menu_item_string;
  }
  $menu_item_json_string = implode(",", $menu_item_json_array);
}

$menu_json_data_string .= $menu_item_json_string;
$menu_json_data_string .= '}';

echo $menu_json_data_string;
```

Ref: http://simple2kx.com/wordpress-create-json-data-page-to-load-menu-items/

Comment: How could you get one more level?  Grandchildren?

Comment: @TJSherrill Now there is a plugin which does this, https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-menus/ If you want to modify the above code itself, try accessing the grandchildren inside nested foreach.